# XMPP Connection Pool

Tags: java, xmpp, connection-pooling

I'm developing service which communicates with users via my own protocol (persistent socket connection). I need to add possibility for users to send and receive messages via XMPP. So, on server I wish to implement connection pool for XMPP connections, but I think it's already done, but google says nothing... Do you now implementations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [XMPPPool](http://github.com/cstar/XMPPPool). I wrote that a long time ago and I don't support it in any way.

However, there it is. I hope you find it useful.

[A bit of documentation is available.](http://cestari.wordpress.com/2007/09/10/xmpppool-xmpp-connection-pooling-for-tomcat/)

Answer (score 0):

Several bosh connection managers do use connection pooling of xmpp connections internally. Here is one i know written in Java: [JabberHTTPBind](http://blog.jwchat.org/jhb/) . You might just want to have a look at it's code for further help.