# Should I destroy explicitly connection pool used as a resource in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, xmpp, connection-pooling

My project is to create a webservice which would connect to a XMPP server and serve as a bridge to send messages to XMPP clients (WS calls -> XMPP messages). Recently, I thought about creating a single connection, which would be shared across all requests (-> my previous question).

But, I was told to create something which would be more scalable and to think about connection pooling. I found a very useful piece of code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718317/xmpp-connection-pool). But, I am afraid of memory leaks in Tomcat container - I've read too much about it;) Here, I've got few questions:

1. If I specify that library as a resource, it is automatically created during context initialization. What about memory leaks after e.g. server shutdown? They aren't destroyed automatically, are they? I understand that I should destroy it manually, creating a ContextListener, but what should I call?
2. If I put into resource definition

   ```
    removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
   ```

   will it help to destroy zombie connections from the pool? Is it a correct solution or just  a sort of recovering after a disaster?

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you shut down the server, then you're shutting down the JVM, and resource leaks won't matter. The only memory leaks you've likely read about in relation to Tomcat is [the PermGen problem](http://www.google.com/search?q=tomcat%20permgen), which plagues webapp development in general. Don't worry about the connection pool. It'll take care of itself.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I see that in reality there is no problem implementing the pool.